# Sharepoint GetListsOfType in Rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there anyway to have similar results of GetListsOfType with REST API. I am trying to get only lists for document library with REST API. 
Similar to this code in C#;

```
 SPListCollection docs = web1.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
```

Or alternatively is there anyway to find a list type (for example DocumentLibrary) from retrieved list from REST API in XML format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows how to retrieve lists of specific type (`101` for `ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary`).

```
Url: /_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101
Method: GET
Headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    Accept: "application/atom+xml"
```